# C# WPF I cannot get value of textbox in Mainwindo.xaml.cs in onther class

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Simply, I am trying to get value in `textbox` to use it in other class,
but it comes in other class empty.

Can you help me please?

This simple code is in mainform:

```
    namespace WpfApplication4

    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public string  GetTxt
            {
                get { return textBox.Text; }
                //set { };
            }

            private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Class1 cls = new Class1();
                cls.txt();

            }
        }
    }
     and this code in class:
    namespace WpfApplication4
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            public void txt()
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(mw.GetTxt);
            }

        }
    }
```

So, can you help me please?

Comment: It's because you're creating a new instance of MainWindow. Add a string parameter to the `txt` method and pass it when it gets call in the button_Click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you see the line `MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();`. This creates a new `MainWindow` object and the default value for its `textBox.Text` is apparently "".
To solve this, you can make the constructor of `Class1` accept a string. And it will also need a string field so that it can be used by `txt` method. So add this constructor to your `Class1`:

```
public Class1(string text){
    _text = text;
}
```

Add this line in the class to add the field : `private string _text;`. Now change your `txt` method like this:

```
public void txt()
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(_text);
}
```

It's all setup now. In the `button_Click` in your `MainWindow` class, change your class declaration as follows:

```
Class1 cls = new Class1(textBox.Text);
```

Or simple, as [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743962/william) suggested, you can have your `txt` class have a string parameter as well. But if you want to use the textbox value in more than 1 method, you want to store it in a field. Else you can just make your method accept it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it's very useful . realy i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked in MainWindow, it creates a new instance of Class1, which creates a NEW MainWindow.  In this new instance of MainWindow, textbox.Text is empty.  You need to call GetText on the existing instance (the one where the button was clicked).